# Styling an upload field

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to style an upload field, and I've already spent many hours trying to fix it without success. I've created a simple [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PXRpk/4/) to demonstrate the problems (if you're into fast-reading read only the bold bullet points).

**Firefox 7**:

- CSS3 rounded corners (ok)
- Text shadow (ok)
- **The hand cursor appears only in the lower half of the label** (not ok, I expect that the hand cursor should be visible hovering any point of the label)

**IE 8**:

- No rounded corners (looks worse, but is ok)
- No text shadow (no problem, I know there is no support for it)
- **The hand cursor appears only in the lower half of the label** (not ok, I expect that the hand cursor should be visible hovering any point of the label)
- **Clicking the upper part of the label the file upload dialog doesn't show** (not ok, I expect the dialog to open by clicking any point of the label, like with FF)
- After clicking it appears a blinking cursor (weird, but who the heck cares about this one)

Anyone has ideas?

**UPDATE**: Based on input received, [here is another approach in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PXRpk/6/): I build a button and I bind the click event of the button to send a click event to the file upload input.

Here is some compatibility testing:

- IE 6 WinXP: works
- IE 7 WinXP: works
- IE 8 Win7: works
- FF 7 Linux: works
- FF 8 Win7: works
- Opera 11 Win7/Linux: doesn't work
- Chrome 15 Win7/Linux: doesn't work
- Safari 3.1 MacOSX: doesn't work

**UPDATE 2**: Getting closer, in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PXRpk/8/) I threw in some browser testing, in case of MSIE or Mozilla I use the new approach, otherwise the old one.

- IE 6 WinXP: works
- IE 7 WinXP: works
- IE 8 Win7: works
- FF 7 Linux: works
- FF 8 Win7: works
- Opera 11 Win7/Linux: doesn't work
- Chrome 15 Win7/Linux: works
- Safari 3.1 MacOSX: works

So I guess Opera doesn't work because of the z-index, going to fix that in the next version.

**UPDATE 3**: [new version](http://jsfiddle.net/PXRpk/11/) that works in Opera too. Opera label height is reduced, so all area of the label is clickable. So now it works in all browsers I care about, and it's acceptable in the look. Problem solved.

Comment: It may look stupid but why not to hide object file and use an image or some as a button?

Comment: To add to that, the hand cursor problem is also an issue in Google Chrome.

Comment: @Márcio because it isn't a button, the upload event is protected by browsers, you can't associate it to an image or a button.

Comment: Actually, the most portable solution I've seen is the one recommended by @Marcio, hide the actual file input and use a regular input and a button as simulations, using Javascript to connect them. There are several examples like this... http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

Comment: @stivlo but you can call it on an event. but nevermind.

Comment: @madth3 I didn't know it was possible, it maybe worth trying the final suggestion: *A reader proposed to remove all the complicated CSS stuff, totally hide the file upload field, and route all click events on the fake upload field to the real one. An excellent idea, and much simpler than the one described above.*

Comment: @Márcio I'm here to learn, I didn't know it was possible, now that I saw the article that madth3 posted, I think it can be a good possibility. Late night here, I will try tomorrow morning and update you guys. Thank you!

Comment: @madth3, I tried to use a button and re-route the input event, see the update. Not sure how compatible that is, going to test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've to answer my question, because other answers are partial solutions that don't work in all browsers. Particularly I'm supporting IE 6, IE 7, IE 8, Chrome 15, Opera 11, FF 7, FF 8, Safari 3.1 on MacOSX. Most likely it will work on other browsers too, but this are the ones I could test with, since I've on my computers and VMs.

In the end my customer opted for a [smaller and more sober version](http://jsfiddle.net/PXRpk/18/). The new version comes also with shorter HTML, JavaScript and CSS.

**HTML**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="">
    <div class="fileupload-buttonbar">       
    </div>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
.file-upload {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;    
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    background: #5A5A5A;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size: 8.5px;
    font-family: Arial;
}

.file-upload:hover {
    background: #808080;
}

.file-upload input {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    z-index:2;
}

.file-upload { height: 14px; width: 115px; }
```

**JavaScript**

```
var html = '';
if ($.browser.mozilla || $.browser.msie) {
    html = '<input type="button" class="file-upload" '
        + 'value="SCEGLI FOTO..."/><input id="uploadfile" '
        + 'name="uploadfile" multiple="" type="file"/>';
    $('.fileupload-buttonbar').html(html);
    $('#uploadfile').hide();
    $('.file-upload').click(function () {
        $('#uploadfile').click();
    });
} else {
    html = '<label class="file-upload"><span>SCEGLI FOTO...</span> '
        + '<input name="uploadfile" multiple="" type="file"/></label>';
    $('.fileupload-buttonbar').html(html);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

IE 8:

add z-index to your input rule.. voila

```
.file-upload input {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0.0);
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Edit: it is easier to see what is happening in FF with the following css...

```
.file-upload {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;    
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #707070;
    background: #A0A0A0;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    text-shadow: #000 1px 1px 4px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.file-upload:hover {
    background: #2FA2FF;
}
.file-upload.focus {
    outline: 2px solid yellow;
}

.file-upload input {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 38px;
    font-size: 12px;
    -moz-opacity:50;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 50;
    z-index:2;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.file-upload span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: .45em;
    z-index:1;
}

.file-upload { height: 38px; }
.file-upload,
.file-upload span { width: 160px; }    

.file-upload-status {
    margin-left: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 7px 11px;
    font-weight: bold;    
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #888;
    background: #f8f8f8;
    border: 3px solid #ddd;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Harry, I've created a [new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PXRpk/5/) with your suggestion. It works great in IE and Chrome, however in FF it's not possible anymore to open the file requester.

Answer (score 0):

So, my suggestion is that you hide your input file and use another object such as an image or an stylized input text to get what you want, right? This very simple code explains what I'm saying:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Teste</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function File()
    {
        var f = document.getElementById("file");
        f.click();
        document.getElementById("file_path").value = f.value; 
    }

    function ReturnFile(f)
    {
        document.getElementById("file_path").value = f.value;
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>

<input type="file" id="file" onchange="ReturnFile(this)" /><br /><br />

<input type="button" onclick="File()" value="Send a file..." />
<div onclick="File()">Send a file...</div>
<a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="File()">Send a file...</a><br />
<img src="your_image.png" onclick="File()" alt="Send a file..." /><br /><br />

<input type="text" id="file_path" />

</body>
</html>
```

Note that the objects with the click event is your button and the text input with id 'file_path' returns the same value of the file input. So when hide the file, you use the text input or whatelse to show the file to user.

Another important thing is that on the third line of `File` function it's set the value of file input to the text input. But it works only in IE cause it stops and waits user return when `click` event is fired. Other browsers doens't waits and pass through it. So I put an `onchange` event on file input to do the same job to work on other browsers.

Hope it can help you...

Comment: Thanks Márcio I prepared a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DGtwF/1/), I am going to test this method, considering only the image "button", all the rest I'm not interested in (file upload, input fields, links).

Comment: Doesn't work in Opera, clicking on the image brings nothing. Please note my update 2 with the list of all browsers that I'm testing and the update 3, with which all browsers in my list work.